# How do I turn Coursera's accessibility mode off?

Tags: web, accessibility, coursera-api

When I visited the coursera website, I accidentally switch to this in the picture. How do I exit this "accessibility mode"?

I've tried clear cookies and delete localstorage, but it still doesn't work.
[image: coursera website in accessibility mode]

Comment: Sorry, but this question is off topic, it isn't related to development at all. You should ask for support on coursera instead.

Comment: What do you mean by accessibility mode? The Explore popup? The skip to main content link is not visible all the time, is it?

Comment: I just tried https://www.coursera.org/ and I don't see a "skip to main" link when TABBING. I also inspected the code and couldn't find any elements with "skip" in them. I **can** get to the "Explore" button and it has `aria-expanded="false"` so I know it has expandable content.  Pressing ENTER opens the "Explore" menu to look like the screenshot but that wouldn't be an "accessibility mode". That's just normal keyboard navigation.

Comment: If I navigate to a course, then I see a "skip to main" but it only appears when I TAB through the page. It shows up as the first focusable element then disappears when I TAB off it. Standard ["skip link"](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Techniques/general/G1.html) behavior.